# Download Problems

Tags: store, app-update

While trying to download an app (I don't want).  I get error messages number 80004004  I don't know what to do and I can't delete the app. Now I can't get to download any downloads - it seems as if the app, named LINE, is blocking any downloads.  Any ideas??

Comment: I had this problem with my lumia 720 once. I went to the service center and asked them. They didn't have any solution. They reinstalled the os and it s

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write to Microsoft tech support. Once I've had a problem with downloading app, but error code was different. Microsoft engineers have fixed something on their side and everything became OK

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the Nokia maps-related apps (Drive, Here, etc.) In end I uninstalled them. That solved the endless notifications about a download needing attention - which always failed if I tried again. A few months later I heard they had sorted it out, so I went to the store and "re-got" my apps. From then on, they've worked fine.

You could try the same without waiting months. Backup your data if you have any in the app, uninstall, then reinstall from the store and restore your data.